# Can not load "IE", it is not registered! error message on Karma

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm using karma to run my js tests on multiple browsers.
the test works on Chrome & Firefox but I can't activate them on IE.

I'm getting the following error message:

> Can not load "IE", it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some
>   plugin?

On my config file

```
SET CHROME_BIN=c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe  
SET FIREFOX_BIN=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe  
SET IE_BIN=C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```

I also tried this

```
SET IE_BIN=C:\Program Files (86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```

I already installed [karma-ie-launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ie-launcher).

Can you help me?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In the configuration file for your project (e.g. karma.config.js), check if you have the plugins listed

```
plugins : [
    'karma-junit-reporter',
    'karma-chrome-launcher',
    'karma-firefox-launcher',
    'karma-opera-launcher',
    'karma-ie-launcher',
    'karma-jasmine'
    ],
```

Comment: Worked for me. I had to add this element though (didn't exist in the file).

Comment: In @angular/cli@6.0.0 you need to install them too like `$ npm i karma-firefox-launcher karma-junit-reporter karma-opera-launcher karma-ie-launcher karma-jasmine --save-dev`

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the IE launcher, from your project directory where you have installed karma, install ie launcher:

```
$ npm install karma-ie-launcher
```

That should create a karma-ie-launcher folder under node_modules(default karma installation folder). 
Mind that 'plugins:[]' configuration simply instruct  Karma what to load, you still have to install the browser launchers if you have not done so in initial Karma installation.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the karma ie launcher, replace the index.js from the following file

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ie-launcher/pull/9

Please let me know if it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Amend Package.Json

I had a similar problem with Chrome. After setting the environment variables as you did, what eventually worked was ensuring the following following entries with the specified version numbers in the package.json's devDependencies:

```
"karma-jasmine": "~0.2.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.2",
```

Then perform:

```
npm update
```

Answer (score 1):

Running karma locally worked for me.

`./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start`

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using npm to manage packages and plugins, so I don't know if the steps I followed are the same for you. I see that your question is two years old, I'm currently working on Karma 0.13.15.

Basically to solve this problem I've performed

```
npm install karma-ie-launcher --save-dev -save
```

This command can be used to download the IE launcher plugin and update karma.config.js.

You can find a list of all launchers here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-ie-launcher

Answer (score -2):

Try wrapping your paths in quotes, e.g.:

```
SET IE_BIN="C:\Program Files (86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

Also, make sure you've installed and configured [Karma IE launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ie-launcher).

Comment: I install it and it's still not working, I also tried to run it from cmd using karma start --browsers IE and that's worked