# Cannot load "ie" it is not registered

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-runner

OK, this question is similar to the one posed here:  [Can not load "IE", it is not registered! error message on Karma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764243/can-not-load-ie-it-is-not-registered-error-message-on-karma)

Except I suspect that user has a problem with differentiating between 32bit and 64bit explorer.  My issue is for 32 bit Explorer running in WinXP.

When I launch karma I get the message "Cannot load IE it is not registered.  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?"   Prior to this, I had installed the ie launcher as well as the Firefox one.  The Firefox one *does* work.

Here are the steps I followed to try and get it to launch:

**1)**  `npm install karma-ie-launcher --save-dev`

no go

**2)**  then I noticed `package.json` for Karma did not have the entries for ie.   So I added them to

devDependencies and, for good measure, peer dependencies

no go

**3)**  then I ran `karma start --log-level debug`   to verify the ie plugin was recognized and loaded.  It was.

**4)** in desperation tried overwriting the `index.js` for ie-launcher with the patch from here: https://github.com/christophercurrie/karma-ie-launcher/blob/64bit/index.js

no go  (though I didn't really expect it to make a difference).

For reference, my IE_BIN is pointing to  `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`

**UPDATE:**  By manually -- in the karma.config file -- adding a plugin section and entry for IE (as suggested below) I can now get karma to attempt to launch IE.  It tries 3x and each time a browser window is opened but karma reports "Cannnot launch IE" and none of the tests get executed.

Oddly if I click on the `debug` button it appears to try and load the tests within IE (I can see HTML from my test fixture appear) but Karma does not report anything.

Comment: Looks like this question is about software use and configuration.  If that's the case, it is better suited to Super User.

Comment: Which version of Karma are you using?

Comment: @glepretre  version 0.10.9

Comment: @user1821052 might be related to : https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ie-launcher/issues/6 ?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, even if the plugin in loaded, you have to specify them it in the config file for karma.
I had the same issue for the coverage one.

At the end of your configuration file just write the list of ALL the plugins you are using:

```
...
plugins: [
  'karma-mocha',
  'karma-coverage',
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-ie-launcher',
]
```

That should work.

Comment: that gets me closer - now at least it tries to launch IE.  But it errors out without giving the details in the console (even while running in debug log mode)

Comment: does anyone know WHY you have to list out the plugins specifically in the config?  It appears to only impact only select plugins? (in my case IE in @MarcoCI's Coverage)

Answer (score 0):

i have observed that this problem (and others) seem to be related to a messed up local node_modules installation. wiping out `node_modules` and doing another `npm install` makes everything work again.