# Karma-coverage not found: But, it is installed

Tags: angularjs, macos, karma-runner, karma-coverage

I used this guide http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/coverage.html to setup my Karma-coverage plugin. Furthermore, it gets installed locally via the package.json file, which looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "myApp",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "devDependencies": {
        "karma-jasmine": "latest",
        "karma-coverage": "latest",
        "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "latest",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "latest",
        "coffee-script": "latest"
    }
}
```

My Karma.conf looks like this:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sun Dec 07 2014 15:51:07 GMT+0100 (CET)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'javascripts/vendor/jquery_211.js',
        'javascripts/vendor/angular.js',
        'javascripts/vendor/angular-route.js',
        'javascripts/vendor/angular-mocks.js',
        '../app/assets/javascripts/app.coffee',
        'javascripts/*.js',
        'test/controllers/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        '../app/assets/javascripts/app.coffee' : ['coffee'],
        '**/javascripts/*.js': 'coverage'
        //'**/*.coffee': ['coffee']
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Now, while running karma I receive the error

```
WARN [reporter]: Can not load "coverage", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.28 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [preprocess]: Can not load "coverage", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
```

It does not matter, if I include karma-coverage in the plugin section of the karma.conf file, the problem stays the same (since the plugin gets loaded locally, I should not need the plugin part anyway...). I hope somebody of you guys has an idea... Thank you!

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076660/cannot-load-ie-it-is-not-registered/22091482#22091482

Comment: Well, as I have said, usage of "plugins: [   'karma-mocha',   'karma-coverage',   'karma-chrome-launcher',   'karma-ie-launcher', ]", does not work...

Comment: So, also with the plugins section, you have the same error or a different one? Did you have any warnings during the installation process?

Comment: The error is exactly the same, when I include the plugin section. The funny thing is that Karma is able to load every plugin except  karma-coverage. But, all Plugins are installed via the same package.json file without any errors resp. warnings. Btw: I'm running it on OSX, maybe this does matter in some way.
Edit: My Plugins section looks like this:     plugins: [
    'karma-jasmine',
    'karma-coverage',
    'karma-chrome-launcher',
    'karma-coffee-preprocessor'
    ],

Comment: Do you have a local or global karma install? Karma uses by default all the plugins that sit in folder siblings to its one.

Comment: its a local installation. Yeah, I have read this line already somewhere, but what is actually meant by 'sibilings to its one'? Siblings on the same hierarchy-level separated by "-" or actual subfolders? Atm. the structure is like this: karma.conf and node_modules on the same folder level, then in node_modules karma, karma-coverage, karma-[...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for this problem was that I had a couple of installed node_modules within my users home folder. After deinstalling these modules and the locally installed ones via npm, I made a clean reinstall via npm link. This solved the problem for me!

Comment: Were the modules in `~/.npm` or actually in a `node_modules` folder somewhere?   Did you just delete them manually?  or did you use `npm prune` to remove?  Thanks!

Comment: as far as I remember, I just deleted them by hand via rm -f %location. Sorry, but I forgot about the path details; however it should be node_modules somewhere in my home folder.

Answer (score 5):

`npm install -g karma-coverage` to install the karma-coverage, and it will work fine, but i don't know why.

```js
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Oct 13 2015 11:14:07 GMT+0800 (CST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      '*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      'karma.config.js'
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      '*.js': 'coverage'
    },

    coverageReporter:{
      type: 'html',
      dir: './coverage'
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress','coverage'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

Comment: `npm install -g karma-coverage` worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-coverage'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
  require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
],

After added **"karma-coverage"** into the plugins array in karma.conf.js
it works to me. Thanks
```